# Garden plant in south of France

Tags: species-identification, botany

When visiting the south of France (around St Tropez) I had a plant in the garden which I initially mistook for mint but the aroma of the leaves (when rubbed) was distinctly different (I cannot put a name on it, it is sweet and remotely reminds of orange).

The plant has bare branches (it is a bush), and beside the leaves there are some round things which I took a picture of (sorry for my abysmal lacks in correct botanical words - these are the last two photos).

The photos are as of end of October.

The leaves are not smooth, they have some kind of tiny barbs which I can feel when rubbing the leave upwards (towards the petiole). The other way round (from the petiole) is smooth.

I cannot tell about the taste yet as my wife suggested that I wait for more information (just kidding).

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]